# System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am using MVC 4.7 version visual studio 2015 express for my we development whenever. While trying to add resource class to support globalisation , following error is raised.

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

**Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "TradeSuiteApp.Web.App_LocalResources.MenuSchedule.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "TradeSuiteApp.Web" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.**

at the following code

```
    public static string MenuScheduletitle {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("MenuScheduletitle",resourceCulture);
        }
   }
```

I would like to know the reason for the error and possible solution for the same.
Thanks in advance for your time – if I’ve missed out anything, over- or under-emphasised a specific point let me know in the comments.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. The resource you have added was not compiled into output assembly. Most likely you have to change the `Build Action` of you resource file to `Embedded Resource` in `Properties` and rebuild.

Comment: @MichalŠuvada Thanks you so much for the help it worked.